# My Ethernet modem disconnects during download at high speed when using proxy software

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, proxy

please my Ethernet modem keeps disconnecting after some seconds or minutes when downloading files at high speed and I have to unplug and re-plug the modem before internet connection is restored. This issue happens when I make use of a proxy software to connect to the internet. I have a feeling that the proxy server disconnects me when the speed is high but I want to know how to auto reconnect my Ethernet modem to the internet when it disconnects(my modem is on auto reconnect but does not connect or download automatically after connection except i unplug it and re-plug.) This makes me stay put to the computer to notice when it has disconnected when downloading so that I can unplug and re-plug to begin again.
(Pardon the long details, it's just that it is really annoying)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Test at a cmd prompt:

`ping -f -l 1500 google.com`

If you get "Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set":

repeat that test by reducing the 1500 by -8 until it replies.

Set the MTU to the highest value that replies with times and does not timeout.

Comment: pls enlighten on the MTU settings (how to set it) this is what i am getting. http://imgur.com/zW6lJD5